# Selecting a date input field in Web form for marketers

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using **Sitecore WFFM** and the date field comes with a drop down list of `dd / mm /YYYY` with a starting date that I define. If I want to use this for DOB field I would like this drop down list to have a `null` value instead of `1 Jan 2000` so the user is forced to select.
How can I enforce a "select" value instead of the default date defined in form designer for that field?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a custom WFFM field by subclassing `Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.DateSelector`.

In the `OnInit` method, insert the empty "select" items at the start of each dropdownlist:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    month.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
    day.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
    year.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

    SelectedDate = String.Empty;
    month.SelectedValue = String.Empty;
    day.SelectedValue = String.Empty;
    year.SelectedValue = String.Empty;
}
```

In order to ensure proper validation, you will also need to override the `Result` property as well as set the `ValidationProperty` attribute on the class itself.

```
[ValidationProperty("Value")]
public class CustomDate : DateSelector 
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) { ... } // See above

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the date field
    /// </summary>
    public new string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (month.SelectedIndex > 0 && day.SelectedIndex > 0 && year.SelectedIndex > 0)
                return DateUtil.ToIsoDate(new DateTime(DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(StartDate).Year + year.SelectedIndex, month.SelectedIndex + 1, day.SelectedIndex + 1).Date);

            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retuns the new result
    /// </summary>
    public override ControlResult Result
    {
        get
        {
            return new ControlResult(base.ControlName, Value, null);
        }
    }
}
```